# Hair points in weird direction

Tags: particles

All of my hair particles point in one direction.
[image]
Regardless of the object. This is the standard cube with the standard particle settings.
[image]
I'm using 2.79.

Comment: Can you add an image of all of your particle settings?

Answer (score 0):

Under *Particle Settings -> Source* enable the check mark *Use Modifier Stack*